# java to scala conversion - generic typings for r-tree lost?

Tags: java, scala, generics, r-tree

I want to use https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree to create

```
RTree<String, Point> tree = RTree.create();
tree = tree.add("someStuff", Geometries.point(10,20));
```

In scala I tried to

```
val tree = RTree.create // note no generics here. Unsure how to add them
tree.add("someStuff", Geometries.point(10,20))
```

This results in 
`cannot resolve symbol 'add' when trying to compile the Scala code`.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, you can just add a type signature: `val tree: Tree[String,Point] = Rtree.create`. In fact, I think that might be all you need to get this to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
val tree: RTree[String, Point] = RTree.create[String, Point]()
tree.add("someStuff", Geometries.point(10,20))
```